# Using Wolfram Language for Non-Relational (NoSQL) Data Storage

Tags: data, entity

I've got a relatively small amount of personal data I'd like to try to store and manipulate within the WolframWorld (tm forthcoming). It's not enough data to spin up a MongoDB instance, but since each "entity" has different properties, it doesn't fit in well with an Excel or Access model.

Here's an `EntityStore` with a sampling of the data:

```
store = EntityStore["Household Equipment" -> <|
    "Entities" -> <|
      "Downstairs Furnace" -> <|"SerialNumber" -> "ABC123", 
        "Output" -> Quantity[125000, "BritishThermalUnitsMean"], 
        "ManufactureDate" -> DateObject[{2005, 2, 15}]|>,
      "Upstairs Furnace" -> <|"SerialNumber" -> "XYZ123", 
        "Output" -> Quantity[125000, "BritishThermalUnitsMean"], 
        "ManufactureDate" -> DateObject[{2005, 3, 12}]|>,
      "Downstairs AC Compressor" -> <|"SerialNumber" -> "MNO456", 
        "Tonnage" -> Quantity[5, "TonsOfRefrigerationUS"], 
        "ManufactureDate" -> DateObject[{2014, 11, 2}]|>
      |>,
    "EntityClasses" -> <|
      "Furnaces" -> <|
        "Entities" -> {"Downstairs Furnace", "Upstairs Furnace"}|>
      |>,
    "Properties" -> <|
      "Age" -> <|
        "DefaultFunction" -> (Today - #["ManufactureDate"] &)|>
      |>
    |>]
```

I've read through a ton of the documentation, but don't know how to accomplish exactly what I'm wanting. Here's my wish list:

1. Local storage preferred, but private Wolfram Cloud(tm) storage acceptable.
2. Query-able like the WDF framework.
3. Ability to be quickly summoned such as with a `Get` or `PersistentValue` model.
4. Ability to add/remove/change entities or properties without having to register/re-register stores.

I've looked at combinations of `EntityStore`, `ResourceObject`, `PersistentObject`, `LocalObject` but can't seem to figure out the best way to do this. And if the answer is "wrong tool for the wrong job", completely understood and I'll look elsewhere.

Comment: It looks like an EntityStore would work well, except for your point 4 on the Wishlist. I thought an association would work, but that is actually also immutable, so a No-Go with your point 4. Hmm...